# looping animations inside a project without copy pasting keyframes

Tags: animation, workflow, looping

I was wondering is it possible to for example make a cube move left and right and fix that animation to the object so that it keeps moving left and right regardless of whether I have created fixed key frames? I think the physics options come closest to what I'm trying to get at but that works of course a little different.

I would like to for example loop complex animations infinitely in a file so I can meanwhile create other animations that aren't looped inside the same file without having to constantly add keyframes whenever the project becomes longer.

I would guess that's possible because in a game a turret might have a looped animation inside the game for movement

Comment: to make an animation cyclic, select the action in the Dope Sheet and press shift E > Make Cyclic. Is it what you want?

Comment: @moonboots yes that is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

To make an animation cyclic, select the action in the *Dope Sheet* and press <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> > *Make Cyclic.*